# regular expression with an array of patterns (in R)

Tags: arrays, regex, r

I'd like to identify all elements of a string that match an array of patterns.  How do I do this?  I'd like to avoid clunky for-loops, because I'd like to have the result be invariant to the order in which I specify the patterns.

Here is a simple (non-working) example.

```
regex = c('a','b')
words = c('goat','sheep','banana','aardvark','cow','bird')
grepl(regex,words)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In grepl(regex, words) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

EDIT:  Sorry, realized that I've seen the answer to this before and just forgotten it -- it'd be     `grepl('(a)|(b)',words)`, but I'd need some way of coercing the array into that form

Comment: What is the expected result?  You need the element of each word that matches? Or the whole word if it contains the regex?  For example,  `unlist(strsplit(words[1], "")) %in% regex` shows that character 3 in `words[1]` matches one of the two characters in `regex`.

Comment: I want true or false, so I can grab the rows of a matrix with certain column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sapply`:

```
> sapply(regex, grepl, words)
         a     b
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE
```

The original question suggested that the above was what was wanted but then it was changed to ask for those elements which contain any element of `regex`.  In that case:

```
> grepl(paste(regex, collapse = "|"), words)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the regular expression itself with a look-ahead. Here's an example of stitching the regular expression together from your search terms (`a` AND `b` should only match `banana`, make sure to set `perl = TRUE` to enable the `(?=...)` lookahead in your regexp). It should work for more complicated patterns as well, take a look at [this tutorial](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/) for details on the look-ahead.

```
search <- c('a','b')
words <- c('goat','sheep','banana','aardvark','cow','bird')
regex <- paste(paste0("(?=.*", search, ")"), collapse = "")
matches <- grepl(regex,words, perl = T)
print(data.frame(words, matches))
```

UPDATE: this is for the original question of matching ALL search terms, matching ANY search terms can be achieved as indicated in the edit to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Some time back, I wrote a function called [**`needleInHaystack`**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/10567936) that can be used as follows:

```
x <- needleInHaystack(regex, words)
x
#          a b
# goat     1 0
# sheep    0 0
# banana   1 1
# aardvark 1 0
# cow      0 0
# bird     0 1
```

Depending on if you want `all` or `any`, it's easy to use `apply` (or `rowSums`).

```
apply(x, 1, function(x) any(as.logical(x)))
#     goat    sheep   banana aardvark      cow     bird 
#     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE 
apply(x, 1, function(x) all(as.logical(x)))
#     goat    sheep   banana aardvark      cow     bird 
#    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE
```

It's designed for finding things even out of order. So, for example, "to" would match "goat". Not sure if that's a behavior you would want for your problem though.